# Can't change Pose Position of Armatures to Rest with Alt-G,R,S combo

Tags: armature, transforms

I just started using blender a few days ago and I've been tinkering around with simple armature models. In previous attempts, when I wanted the armature reset, I would do the Alt-G,R,S combo or 'Clear Transform' but now it doesn't seem to work. Is there an alternative option to explicitly replace the pose position with the rest position?

Ideally, I'd like to actually use the "Rest Position" Armatures for pose changes. 
Earlier, I've tried to look for a method like this just to give an idea of what I'm trying to do: 
1. Copy the Armature from the "Rest Position" tab 
2. Proceed to the "Pose Position" tab, delete the Pose Position and...
3. Replace it with the "Rest Position" Armature so I can translate it since I'm in "Pose Position" mode. 
That hasn't worked out for me and I'm stumped.

Edit: Nvm, just found out that the difference between resetting the "Pose Position" and "Rest Position" is that "Rest Position" doesn't take into consideration the **effect of the IK constraints**.

Answer (score 1):

Enter pose mode, right click to open the pose context menu, and select "Clear User Transforms." In its options make sure "Only Selected" is unchecked. This will clear all pose on the armature, including unselected or hidden bones.

[image: The Pose Context Menu]
[image: Clear User Transforms Options]

Answer (score -1):

In the properties panel, under the armature settings you can reset the pose to the rest position by selecting "Rest Position."

[image]

Comment: The problem with that is I can't change poses when "Rest Position" is enabled.